# My gulp usemin task missing a js file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, gulp, gulp-usemin

I am using gulp usemin task to combine and minimize/uglify the css and js files in my HTML.

```
gulp.task('usemin',['jshint'], function () {
  return gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
      .pipe(usemin({
        css:[minifycss(),rev()],
        js: [uglify(),rev()]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

And my blocks in HTML:

```
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/home.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

But after I have done this. in the dist/, all other parts work well as they are in app/ but **jquery-ui.js**. The color animation in my page doesn't work, which is due to jquery-ui.

file structure:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrU4S.jpg)

How could this be? Only one js file doesn't work, but others works fine?

Comment: Could you show your file structure. Perhaps it's a path issue

Comment: @Michael I uploaded a screenshot of file structure.

Answer (score 0):

I find it out by myself.
I need to add the jquery-ui css file for color animation into HTML like this:

```
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">

<link href="styles/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

But I am still not so sure why I can use jquery-ui without any problems before I minimize the CSS files.

Comment: I got an error when using files including 'min' in the filename. Something like: Error: write callback called multiple times…